# Django Page Load slowed based on variable local to view code

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am using Django to display a series of test results.  I created a view to show the most recent instance of each test result.

```
1: results = resultTable.objects.order_by('id')
2: latestResults = {}
3: for res in results: latestResults[res.testcase.name] = res.id
4: latestResultQuerySet = resultTable.objects.filter(id__in=latestResults.values())
5: del latestResults
6: return HttpResponse()
```

Line 1 creates a QuerySet of about 20,000 entries in about 1 second.

Line 3 calculates the id of the latest results of each testcase in about 12 seconds.

Line 4 create a new QuerySet of about 800 entries using those ids in about 1 second.

Line 5 deletes the dictionary in essentially no time.

From this I would think the (blank) page would load in about 15 seconds.  In practice it take about 3 minutes to load.

Removing line 3 allows the page to load instantly.

Any ideas what is causes the extra 2+ minutes of delay?  Since I am not passing anything to the HttpResponse I assumed it had something to do with the garbage collection of the dictionary, thus line 5 was born.

Comment: Check the logic. You are just doing the exact same thing - Get all the ids ordered by id in the 2 queries.

Comment: karthikr - The the queries aren't the same.  The second query is just getting the distinct subset of the first.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are having an [n + 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue) issue

If so you are doing 20,000 queries as you loop through the result set.

you can use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to avoid this:

```
results = resultTable.objects.select_related('testcase').order_by('id')
```

Comment: Good but not great.  This reduced the action of line 3 to 1.8 seconds but the page load is still over a minute.

Answer (score 0):

If I can second guess the logic from your code, you are trying to find latest ids with distinct values of `testcase.name`. The only way to improve performance is to avoid building a huge dictionary in memory from a queryset. So here is an attempt to turn it into a simple query:

```
latestResultQuerySet = resultTable.objects.order_by('testcase__name', 'id').distinct('testcase__name')
```

Comment: distinct only accepts parameters for POSTgreSQL.  Unfortunately my DB is MySQL.